# Conditional statement to show pagination

Tags: theme-development, customization, pagination

I'm using pagination to navigate between posts from the same category.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="article_single_prev_next">
    <div class="article_prev">
        <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Article Précédent', TRUE); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="article_next">
        <?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Article Suivant', TRUE);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly.

But what I am trying to do is to add an `if` statement, to show the div with ID `article_single_prev_next` only if there are next of previous pages inside the category.

I tried using this code without success:

```
<?php if (show_posts_nav('%link')) : ?>
    <div class="article_single_prev_next">
        <div class="article_prev">
            <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Article Précédent', TRUE); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="article_next">
            <?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Article Suivant', TRUE);?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this like so:

```
<?php
$next_post_link = get_next_post_link( '%link', 'Article Précédent', TRUE );
$previous_post_link = get_previous_post_link( '%link', 'Article Suivant', TRUE );
?>
<?php if ( $next_post_link || $previous_post_link ) : ?>
    <div class="article_single_prev_next">
        <div class="article_prev">
            <?php echo $next_post_link; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="article_next">
            <?php echo $previous_post_link; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks but it's not working... my div "article_single_prev_next" is never displayed when using this code... maybe I need to add args inside the if statement ?

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: thanks it works, I had only to add "get" on line 3 $previous_post_link = get_previous_post_link( '%link', 'Article Suivant', TRUE );